# Compilation failed when I use sbt to build spark self-contained application

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

I was trying to build a complication by using sbt.

Code: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/ALSExample.scala

Tutorial: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications

But errors happened.

```
[error] /home/zeng/workspace/spark/als/src/main/scala/ALSExample.scala:22:object ml is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[error] import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
[error]                         ^
[error] /home/zeng/workspace/spark/als/src/main/scala/ALSExample.scala:23: object ml is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[error] import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS
[error]                         ^
[error] /home/zeng/workspace/spark/als/src/main/scala/ALSExample.scala:25: object sql is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[error] import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
[error]                         ^
[error] /home/zeng/workspace/spark/als/src/main/scala/ALSExample.scala:46: not found: value SparkSession
[error]     val spark = SparkSession
[error]                 ^
[error] /home/zeng/workspace/spark/als/src/main/scala/ALSExample.scala:61: not found: type ALS
[error]     val als = new ALS()
[error]                   ^
[error] 5 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Why did this happened? BTW, spark verion is 2.0.0.

Comment: what does your build.sbt file look like? It looks like you are not specifying the library correctly.

Comment: @GameOfThrows build.sbt file:`name := "ALSExample"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so just as suspected, this error reflect on the fact that you did not include all the spark libraries in your build file, the ones you are missing is (are?) :

```
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.0.0"
```

if you are using Dataframes, you will also need:

```
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0"
```